# Split a string by php's delimiters itself

Tags: php, regex, string

I am trying to extract php code from a long file. I wish to throw away the code not in a PHP tags. Example

```
<html>hello world, its a wonderful day</html>
<?php echo $user_name; ?> Some more text or HTML <?php echo $datetime; ?> 
I just echoed the user_name and datetime variables.
```

I want to return an array with:

```
array(
    [1] =>  "<?php echo $user_name; ?>"
    [2] =>  "<?php echo $datetime; ?>"
)
```

I think I can do this with regex but im not an expert. Any help? Im writing this in PHP. :)

Comment: A great place to start learning about Regex is [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to view the source code in order to see the results, but this is what I came up with:

```
$string = '<html>hello world, its a wonderful day</html>
<?php echo $user_name; ?> Some more text or HTML <?php echo $datetime; ?> 
I just echoed the user_name and datetime variables.';

preg_match_all("/<\?php(.*?)\?>/",$string,$matches);

print_r($matches[0]); // for php tags
print_r($matches[1]); // for no php tags
```

**Update:** As mentioned by [Revent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1570024/revent), you could have `<?=` for shorthand echo statments. It would be possible to change your `preg_match_all` to include this:

```
$string = '<html>hello world, its a wonderful day</html>
<?php echo $user_name; ?> Some more text or HTML <?= $datetime; ?> 
I just echoed the user_name and datetime variables.';

preg_match_all("/<\?(php|=)(.*?)\?>/",$string,$matches);

print_r($matches[0]); // for php tags
print_r($matches[1]); // for no php tags
```

Another alternative is to check for `<?`(space) for the shorthand php statement. You can include a space (`\s`) to check for this:

```
preg_match_all("/<\?+(php|=|\s)(.*?)\?>/",$string,$matches);
```

I guess it just depends on how "strict", you want to be.

**Update2:** [MikeM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565512/mikem) does make a good point, about being aware of line breaks. You may run into an instance where your tags run over into the next line:

```
<?php 
echo $user_name; 
?>
```

This can easily be solved by using the `s` modifier to `skip linbreaks`:

```
preg_match_all("/<\?+(php|=|\s)(.*?)\?>/s",$string,$matches);
```

Comment: PHP can sometimes use short tags too like <?=, so you might want to add to your example.

Comment: You might want to add the singleline flag so `.` matches across newlines, i.e. `/s`.

Comment: The lie breaks was throwing me off, how awesome I came back to comment and the issue was already solved!! Thank you all.